# Using the sites framework, can I create a link between sites?

Tags: django, django-cms

I have 2 sites setup with Django CMS with the following pages:

Site 1:

- Terms (app_hook is linked to my `Terms` app)

Site 2:

- Home

On Site 1, if I use `reverse('terms')` in a template I get `/terms`.

If I do the same thing on Site 2, I get `Reverse for 'terms' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

How can I link from Site 1, to an app that is hooked on Site 2? Have I missed something glaringly obvious?

Using:

- Django 1.4.5
- django-cms 2.4.3

Many thanks.

Comment: Don't think it's possible to do that .. see https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1229